# replace multiple key value in one line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

How can i replace values of keys in one like , example :

```
 <inline-jdbc isolation-level="ReadCommitted" jdbc-driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                           jdbc-password="xxxxxx" jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://xxxxx"

                            jdbc-username="xxxxx"
                            time-between-eviction-runs-millis="600000" />
```

as you can see jdbc-password and jdbc-uri are in same line if i run the following command :

```
s/\(jdbc-uri *= *\).*/\1"jdbc:mysql:\/\/xxxx"/g
s/\(jdbc-password *= *\).*/\1"xxxx"/g
s/\(jdbc-username *= *\).*/\1"xxxx"/g
```

this command replace jdb-password and jdbc-username and remove jdbc-uri !!

Comment: You can use `"[^"]"` instead of `.*` to find what is between the apostrophes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `"[^"]+"`

Comment: Indeed, the immediate problem is that you are matching the entire rest of the file with `.*` and replacing it with nothing. More fundamentally, using regex to manipulate a well-defined structured format is misdirected.